# proof translation property of transform fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

I really need your help here:

Think of $f(x,y)$ as an image where the dimensions are: $NxM$.

I can't prove this property of 2D transform fourier:

if the transform of $f(x,y)$ is $F(u,v)$ so the transform of
$f(x-x_0,y-y_0)$  is  $F(u,v)e^{-2{\pi}i(ux_0/{N}+ vy_0/M)}$

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: simply apply the change of variable $(x',y') =(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ in the integral

Comment: I tried but i'm stuck.. i know this should be simple... can you please write this? I will appreciate it.

Comment: do it in dimension $1$ first

Comment: I dont know what to do with the sigma..I can't just split it..

Comment: write first your formula for the Fourier transform. and proofs of the translation property of the FT can be found everywhere on the internet.

Comment: the formula is: $F(u,v)=\frac{1}{NM}\Sigma^{N-1}_{x=0}\Sigma^{M-1}_{y=0}f(x,y)e^{-2\pi{i}(\frac{ux}{N}+\frac{vy}{M})} $

after changing $x$ by $x-x_0$ and  $y$ by $y-y_0$ we will get:
$F'(u,v)=\frac{1}{NM}\Sigma^{N-1}_{x=0}\Sigma^{M-1}_{y=0}f(x-x_0,y-y_0)e^{-2\pi{i}(\frac{u(x-x_0)}{N}+\frac{v(y-y_0)}{M})}$

and after few trival steps:
$F'(u,v)=\frac{1}{NM}\Sigma^{N-1}_{x=0}\Sigma^{M-1}_{y=0}f(x-x_0,y-y_0)e^{-2\pi{i}(\frac{ux}{N}+\frac{vy}{M})}e^{2\pi{i}(\frac{ux_0}{N}+\frac{vy_0}{M})}$

what can I do now? 
I searched this proof for a week and I was failed..

Comment: Study a Discrete Fourier transform course !!!
in dimension $1$ :

$$DFT[f(n)](k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(n) e^{-2 i \pi n k/N}$$

with $f(n+N) = f(n)$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ :

$$DFT[f(n-a)](k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(n-a) e^{-2 i \pi n k/N} = \sum_{m=-a}^{N-1-a} f(m) e^{-2 i \pi (m+a) k/N} = \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} f(m) e^{-2 i \pi (m+a) k/N} = e^{-2 i \pi a k/N} DFT[f(n)](k)$$

Comment: and you are talking of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) not the general Fourier transform. if you want to prove the formula for non integer shifts, you have to study the general Fourier transform or the Fourier series, the sampling and convolution theorems, etc.